# Preventing Pages theme from being imposed on each aspx page directive during compilation

Tags: asp.net, web-config, themes

in my web.config i use the following pages declaration

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" Theme="Theme1">
```

with the intention of being able to use different themes on a web application to customize the way it displays for a few different clients(some of which want their own branding on the web application's pages)

if i leave out the theme directive in my development code, it doesn't display properly when debugging, so i want to have the Theme defined in the web.config... however when it is defined as above and i go to publish my solution every .aspx page declaration goes from this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" CodeFile="MRSHome.aspx.vb"%>
```

to this:

```
<%@ page language="VB" inherits="App_Web_peiwi24o" theme="Theme1" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" %>
```

and page level theme declarations override the ones set in the web.config file, i need that to remain the case since some pages programmatically switch to a print friendly theme when the user needs it.

How do i prevent the web.configs pages settings from being appended to each page's page declaration during compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring the theme in web.config page declaration, you can add a appsettings in webconfig:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyCustomTheme" value="Theme1" />
</appSettings>
```

And in form PreInit you can set the theme for the page:

```
Protected Sub WebForm1_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        Dim myTheme As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyCustomTheme")
        Page.Theme = myTheme 
End Sub
```

So, when you deploy, your page declaration will not contain any theme. In runtime it will pickup the correct theme defined in config.